# Detect if an iFrame link is opened in a new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, single-page-application

In my application which is a SPA, I have an iFrame which is of another internal app. I want my app to reload whenever the user tries to open any link in a new tab from the internal app. How can I achieve this?

I tried achieving the above behaviour via the attached code, but it doesn't work when the link is opened in a new tab.

```
const isIframe = () => {
  try {
    return window.self !== window.top;
  } catch (e) {
    return true;
  }
};

const redirectIfIframe = (url) => {
  let previousUrl = url;
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    if (location.href !== previousUrl) {
      previousUrl = location.href;
      window.location.href = url;
      if (isIframe()) {
        window.location.href = url;
      }
    }
  });
  const config = { subtree: true, childList: true };
  observer.observe(document, config);
};
```

Comment: A MutationObserver watches for changes in the DOM tree, not sure what you think that had to do with the current location? The location is not part of the DOM.

Comment: And what "previous" and "current" URL you want to compare here, I don't get either. How could a _newly opened_ tab have any "previous" URL?

Comment: _"via the attached code"_ - not even clear _where_ this is supposed to run now - inside the iframe, or the "parent" app?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, the attached code works only for the current tab, and not the new tab. That's where I am stuck, and requested help.

Comment: @CBroe I want whenever a user clicks on any link within an iFrame and tries to open it in a new tab, I want to prevent that and reload my parent app.

Comment: There is no real, sure-fire way to do that. You can try and make pages in different windows "communicate" somehow, via localStorage/sessionStorage, and have the newly opened one "notify" its creator ... (I think `postMessage` is out here, because you don't have a window reference to post any message to.)

Answer (score 0):

Due to cross-origin restrictions, in most cases, you can't listen to click events within an iframe.

If you don't need to open links within an iframe in the original tab, set [iframe sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/html/element/iframe) like: `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"`.

Another approach is to put your application into Electron.